# How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I have the following Python code:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES var1, var2, var3,")
```

where `var1` is an integer, `var2` and `var3` are strings.

How can I write the variable names without Python including them as part of the query text?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

Note that the parameters are passed as a tuple, `(a, b, c)`. If you're passing a single parameter, the tuple needs to end with a comma, `(a,)`.

The database API does proper escaping and quoting of variables. Be careful not to use the string formatting operator (`%`), because

1. It does not do any escaping or quoting.
2. It is prone to uncontrolled string format attacks e.g. [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Interesting, why does it work with the vars separately instead of in an array (var1,var2,var3)?

Comment: According to the DB API specs, it looks like it can be either way: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Comment: @thekashyap Read again carefully. What's insecure is using the string formatting operator `%`. In fact, I say so in the answer.

Comment: my bad.. I imagined a `%`  instead of `,` beteween the string and variables.. can't undo my vote-down due to various reasons.. I personally would like to see words like insecure / attack etc mentioned in the description where you say don't use `%`..

Comment: Coud you maybe update your answer? I used ? instead of %s because the latter threw an sqlite3 error

Comment: Python converts values in tuple to a data type that MySQL understands and adds the required quotes.

Comment: Downvoted because answer says not to use `%` but uses it three times. More explanation would be great.

Comment: @eric the answer says do not use the `%` *operator* to format the string.  Those `%` in the string are being used by `cursor.execute` directly, and since it knows it's generating SQL it can do more to protect you.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html
https://www.athenic.net/posts/2017/Jan/21/preventing-sql-injection-in-python/

Answer (score 90):

Different implementations of the Python DB-API are allowed to use different placeholders, so you'll need to find out which one you're using -- it could be (e.g. with MySQLdb):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

or (e.g. with sqlite3 from the Python standard library):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

or others yet (after `VALUES` you could have `(:1, :2, :3)` , or "named styles" `(:fee, :fie, :fo)` or `(%(fee)s, %(fie)s, %(fo)s)` where you pass a dict instead of a map as the second argument to `execute`).  Check the `paramstyle` string constant in the DB API module you're using, and look for paramstyle at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/ to see what all the parameter-passing styles are!

Answer (score 68):

Many ways. **DON'T** use the most obvious one (`%s` with `%`) in real code, it's open to [attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Here copy-paste'd **[from pydoc of sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sqlite3.html)**:

> ... beware of using Python’s string operations to assemble queries, as they are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders). For example, an attacker can simply close the single quote and inject OR TRUE to select all rows:

```py
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = input()

sql = "SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol
print(sql)

cur.execute(sql)
```

**More examples if you need:**

```
# Multiple values single statement/execution
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=? OR symbol=?', ('RHAT', 'MSO'))
print c.fetchall()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN (?, ?)', ('RHAT', 'MSO'))
print c.fetchall()
# This also works, though ones above are better as a habit as it's inline with syntax of executemany().. but your choice.
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=? OR symbol=?', 'RHAT', 'MSO')
print c.fetchall()
# Insert a single item
c.execute('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', ('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00))
```

Comment: Some of the DB-API implementations actually use %s for their variables -- most notably psycopg2 for PostgreSQL. This is not to be confused (though it easily is) with using %s with the % operator for string replacement.

I would be really nice if, for portability, we could just have a defined standard way of specifying SQL parameters for DB-API.

Answer (score 28):

[http://www.amk.ca/python/writing/DB-API.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20090504233107/amk.ca/python/writing/DB-API.html)

Be careful when you simply append values of variables to your statements:
Imagine a user naming himself `';DROP TABLE Users;'` --
That's why you need to use SQL escaping, which Python provides for you when you use `cursor.execute` in a decent manner. Example in the URL is:

```
cursor.execute("insert into Attendees values (?, ?, ?)", (name, seminar, paid))
```

Comment: Actually, it is not SQL escaping.  It's variable binding, which is far simpler and more direct.  The values are bound into the SQL statement after parsing, making it immune to any injection attack.

Comment: well, whether it's SQL escaping or variable binding depends on how good or bad your database server / DB-API driver is. I've seen some real-world, widely-deployed production databases that have their DB-API driver just do escaping, rather than keeping data and code out-of-band on the wire. Needless to say, I don't have very much respect for those so-called "databases".

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for providing a single value can be confusing for inexperienced Python users.

Given the query

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (fruit) VALUES (%s)
```

Generally*, the value passed to `cursor.execute` must be wrapped in an ordered sequence such as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) or [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) even though the value itself is a singleton, so we must provide a single element tuple, like this: `(value,)`.

```py
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable (fruit) VALUES (%s)""", ('apple',))
```

Passing a single string

```py
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable (fruit) VALUES (%s)""", ('apple'))
```

will result in an error which varies by the DB-API connector, for example

- psycopg2:

  > TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
- sqlite3

  > sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied
- mysql.connector

  > mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

---

*  The pymysql connector handles a single string parameter without erroring.  However it's better to wrap the string in a tuple even if it's a single because

- you won't need to change the code if you switch connector package
- you keep a consistent mental model of the query parameters being a sequence of objects rather than a single object.